# Accented characters : difference before and after compilation

Tags: java, netbeans, diacritics, non-ascii-characters

I made a light apps which read the HTML code of a page and display it to the user.

During the developement whith NetBeans, no problems at all, but when I use the .jar given by this IDE after a "Clean Build", I have some troubles with the accents.

For exemple, the french word `"renégocier"`, was displayed as such under NetBeans.
But with the clean build of NetBeans, the word is displayed `"renÃ©gocier"` ...

Any idea?

EDIT : this is how I read the HTML code :

```
URL urlObject=null;
URLConnection con=null;
String inputLine;
String codeHTML

urlObject = new URL(UrlToVerification);
con = urlObject.openConnection();
BufferedReader webData = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

while ((inputLine = webData.readLine()) != null)
{
    codeHTML += inputLine; // Lecture du code HTML
 }
```

SOLUTION :

Replace:

```
BufferedReader webData = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
```

with :

```
BufferedReader webData = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlObject.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: where is the string coming from?  a source file?  a resource file?  downloading from a url?  local file?

Comment: Its coming from an URL. I read the HTML code and display some parts of it.

Comment: show the code.  (you are most likely using the wrong character encoding to convert the html bytes to a String, but hard to say specifically without your code).

Comment: add the code to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is using the platform default character encoding when reading the url content.  Instead, you need to pass an explicit character encoding to the `InputStreamReader`.  This should be the encoding specified by the url itself (this should be included in the `"Content-Type"` header).  if the character encoding is not included in the relevant header, then you need to pick an appropriate default.

Comment: Nice! For an UTF8 encoding : BufferedReader webData = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())); THANKS !

Comment: @Eric - did you mistype that?  for a utf-8 encoding, you would want `InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")`.